# Worst possible matchup pre flop

Tags: odds

Statistically what is the worst possible hole card matchup pre flop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

K♠K♥ vs. K♦2♠ (and the other equivalent combinations--those with different suits, as long as the suit of the deuce matches one of the opposing kings).  About a 19-1 dog.